# Can we prevent the TypeScript compiler from following path references in typings?

Tags: typescript

One of the typings for my TypeScript project has a reference that I would like for the compiler to avoid crawling into (because it does not exist).

```
<reference path="../webcomponents.js/webcomponents.js.d.ts"/>
```

Can we set a compiler flag to disable following references? In my case, manually deleting the references would be inconvenient - I unfortunately lack control over the file contents of typings.

Comment: did you try [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)?

Comment: how are you adding your typings? Where are you sourcing them from? I believe DefinitelyTyped has been using `///<reference types` which should have different behavior.